# meteor jasmine: jquery does not work in integration tests

Tags: jquery, meteor, jasmine-jquery

I use meteor with jasmine to create integration tests such as:

```
describe('home', function() {
  it('should check if the homepage is loaded', function() {
          var logoText = $('#logoName').text();
          console.log(logoText);
          expect(logoText == "Welcome").toBe(true);
  });
});
```

This does not work unfortunately. When I lookup the `$('#logoName').text()` the text is correct but it is not returned in the test scenario.

The same thing seems to work with google chrome sometimes.

Do I have to wait until the DOM is loaded or is something wrong with the test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    this.deferAfterFlush(done);
});
```

that should wait for DOM elements to be created